# Load only the new rows in the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a question, How can you load only the new rows in the database and display them to a page, Should I use a **timestamp** to do that? How *Facebook* or *Twitter* load only the new tweets or posts? I guess they use **timestamp** for that, Like when was the last ajax call or something. I know the SQL query, I think It looks something like this.

**SQL**: `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posted_date >= :timestamp`, Where timestamp is the current timestamp, Or the requested timestamp.

But whenever I enter any number, Even more than the `posted_date`, It always returns true, and it returns rows, I don't want that.

Here is my PHP code:

```
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;', 'root', '');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `posted_date` >= :curr_time";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':curr_time', $timestamp);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        // If there was a result found
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode(array(
            'post_content' => $rows[0]['post_content'],
            'timestamp'    => strtotime($rows[0]['posted_date'])
            )); 
    } else {
        // If there was no results
        echo json_encode(array('message' => 'No results!'));
    }
```

I hope you understand me.

Thanks :)

Comment: The whole "problem" you're having revolves around defining what a "new" row is. Since **you** have to tell **us** what you consider a  *new* row, this question is incomplete because it's unclear what you're after. We can't cast black magic for you.

Comment: By new, I'm guessing you mean most recent? You need to store a timestamp/datetime on each record, and then order by that

Comment: The new row is the post_content, I just did that for testing and stuff, So think about it like this, User posts something to database just like Facebook's post, And I want to return only that new post from the database, Not all of them...

Comment: Make sure you are using an auto increment primary key (id) for each record, and then get that after the `INSERT` using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is, Use long polling and stuff like that, So when the user1 posts something, It gets updated in user2's page also, Just like Facebook, I don't need the AJAX and jQuery for now, Just the PHP part, I guess using `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posted_date >= :curr_time` is correct way to do that. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: You can select a single row and order it by id or by the created date. Something like: `SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Yeah you can do that, But what If there was multiple posts at the same time?

Comment: There will always only be one last post, and that's the one that the SELECT statement will get. Even if there are multiple posts at what seems like the exact same time, they will still be stored in the order they are processed by the server, so one will always be the newest post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61165/discussion-between-eskimo-and-akar).

Comment: What is the value of `$timestamp`?

Comment: You don't even need a timestamp (thought it is recommended).  Depending on the number of associations, you can have a `posts_users` table (made up of `post_id`, `user_id`, and a `has_seen` boolean field).  When it's been seen, update the table to true.  Order descending by `posts.post_timestamp` (joined from `post_id`) and voila.

Comment: What is the format of timestamp you are putting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I solved it. This is what I did...

First: I created a file that stored the current `timestamp` of the server and echoed out in a JSON format.

This is the **getServerTime.php** file.

```
// Get the current server time as a UNIX timestamp.
echo json_encode(array(
    'server_time' => time()
));
```

And when the page fully loads I make an AJAX call to that file and store the response. in this case, `server_time` as a variable, So I can use it later...

```
// When the page fully loads, We need to get the timestamp
// Create a function that returns server time
function get_server_time () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/getServerTime.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            return server_time = data.server_time;
        }
    });
}
// We need to call it now, Why? Because the page is loaded.
get_server_time();
```

Now I need to create a Javascript function that will AJAX to **getNewPosts.php** and return the rows from there, So here is the function:

```
$('#get_new_posts').click(function (event) {
    // We need to pass the server timestamp as a variable
    // Because we use it when we query our database
    function get_new_posts(timestamp) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'ajax/getNewPosts.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: 'timestamp=' + timestamp,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                get_server_time();
            }
        });
    }
    // Remember when we set the `server_time` variable to the current server time?
    // We need it now, To call our function
    get_new_posts(server_time);
});
```

Now here is what's inside of **getNewPosts.php**, It's self explainatory, I guess.

```
<?php
    // Set the header to JSON
    header('Content-type: application/json');


    // Get the timestamp from the url, Because we pass it through the AJAX call
    // If there is one, Then we set it to the GET variable
    // Other wise, We set it to null.
    $timestamp = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? $_GET['timestamp'] : null;
    // I have to format the date to get it working
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);

    // Database query
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'akar', 'raparen');

    // Select the posts that are newer than the last ajax call
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `posted_date` >= :timestamp';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':timestamp', $date);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    // If there was any results, Display them
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo json_encode($rows);
    } else {


     // Otherwise, No new posts.
     echo json_encode(array(
         'message' => 'There are no new posts...'
        ));
    }
```

And that solved my problem, I hope you guys at least have a clue, What I'm talking about.

Thanks!

Comment: You could be wrong because it may work for one user, but not for multiple, some collisions will occur inevitable

Comment: I just did that for testing, I will do some other stuff, If there are multiple users.

Comment: there is no need to store time to file manually, when you can do it with session easily :)))

Comment: not only this is the wrong answer it is much more complicated, just have an index on the table you must have one anyway and get the records that have an Id > the bigger id you have on the client.Plus this do not work because if you have new records while the page is loading you never see them.

Answer (score 3):

You can just store `ID` of last loaded element, you can save it in session also, and next time you got the request, you get post by:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE posted_id > :last_loaded_post_id
```

Also you can have restriction by `posted_date` to always require the posts date to be greater or equal to `CURDATE()`, but this may not be optimal, because when it's to come tomorrow after 23:59 pm, you may lose some posts. So storing and depending on the last loaded item id is the best solution I think.

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE posted_id > :last_loaded_post_id 
    AND posted_date >= CURDATE() /* to ensure posts from today */
```

You can also manage it from Javascript, by depending on last post and get it's `post_id` attribute, and pass it with ajax request, but for more security, better to be managed from server-side

**Also problem in your code:** It will always return 1 result, even if there are more

```
// If there was a result found
// this will always return first row, even if there are some more rows
 $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 echo json_encode(array(
     'post_content' => $rows[0]['post_content'],
     'timestamp'    => strtotime($rows[0]['posted_date'])
     ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
WHERE `post_date` >= :curr_time
```

You could simply ORDER the results using the field `post_date` in DESCENDING mode. If you do so then the latest posts will be shown first. Your query would look something like

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `post_date` DESC
```

If you try this approach, do not forget to LIMIT your results. You can still use the WHERE field to fill your needs. If you want to limit your posts to, let's say, 10 latest posts simply run

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `post_date` LIMIT 0,10
```

This will return 10 rows starting from the latest post.

P.S.: I am assuming that by "new" post you mean the "latest" ones, ordered by the date they were added to the database.

Comment: I would imagine this to be very slow, I believe, by default, MySQL indexes are stored as ascending (if you have an index on post_date at all).

Answer (score 1):

So according to your comments you want to eventually implement polling to get the last record created (by user A) and display it for user B

So, assuming you have the insert statement working correctly, to get the last created record is simply:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

This assumes you have an auto incrementing primary key called `id`, if not (you probably should have!), you can use the created date, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1
```